Setting option limit order sizes, given instantaneous Gamma and delta hedging
Lets say we are long gamma, i.e. long a vanilla call or a put option, and we want to delta hedge our position using only limit orders. At time $t$, we own a single 40D Call contract (100 calls), and we short 40 spot to be $\Delta_t=0$. If $S_t$ increases, $\Delta_t$ will increase for the call option and it will hit the ask LO, which would be another short position. If the spot increases by 1, our $\Delta$ will increase by $\Gamma$, so it makes intuitive sense the units to hedge would be approximately equal to $\Gamma$. So we would have $\Gamma$ units $\\\$1$ from the best ask. The same logic applies for buy orders on the bid side for when the spot decreases.
Now lets say we want to have multiple LO's, not just 1. This is for cases when the spot gaps, lets say,  $dS_{t+1}=5$. Then we would have needed multiple LO's across multiple depths. How would we calculate the units acquired across what depths?
If $dS_{t+1}=2$, then it would make sense to have a $units=\Gamma$ at $\\\$S_t+1$ and if we are going further away from ATM, have $units=\Gamma-\epsilon$ at$\\\$S_t+2$. But if the spot gaps hard, we would get our 2 LO's filled, but wouldn't the realized volatility increase and thus increase the price of the option? And so shouldn't would require more units at the 2nd, 3rd and 4th levels in the event it does gap? (We would then edit, i.e. reduce the unit sizes if the spot slowly increased).
What would the best approach be to calculating these limit order units and is there any literature on this topic?
